# Download individual ARN reports from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-console, gsutil, android-anr-dialog, google-play-developer-api

I am in need of downloading reports of individual instances of ANRs (application not responding) data. This in order to upload such data to an internal system that would help me generate reports that are not available on Google Play (ANR rate, Contribution of individual ANR to rate and others) and track ANRs as if they were crashes.

I have been doing some online research and the only thing I can find is the daily generated reports (aggregated monthly) that contain the raw number of ANRs but there is not any detail on the individual instances. 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export

I don't necessarily need a downloadable CVS report, access to the data through gsutil or any other coding tool would be preferred.

I know the data I am looking for exists as it is visible on GooglePlay console under "App> Android Vitals> ANRs & crashes" however I am having trouble finding a way to download it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the data I need from GooglePlay?

If Google Play console simply doesn't offer it, do you have any suggestions on what's the best way to detect ANR on runtime? I can then upload its data as a crash to my internal analytics system.